# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ON_START for Android Arch Lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, android-library, application-lifecycle

I am having a library for SDK that extends both `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, LifecycleObserver. In the constructor, I am registering the class as an observer for ProcessLifecycleOwner.

`ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);`

For the method that does **ON_START** work, I have added the following annotation for the same.

`@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)`

This works completely fine in a local and testing environment. Even for the release version, it works fine. But very rarely it fails with the following **error:**

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ON_START
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:929)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:685)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:170)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:301)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache.createInfo(SourceFile:124)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache.hasLifecycleMethods(SourceFile:59)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.resolveObserverCallbackType(SourceFile:137)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getObserverConstructorType(SourceFile:119)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getCallback(SourceFile:57)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.<init>(SourceFile:347)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(SourceFile:162)
```

This error is very rare. I have only seen this happen for Android 5.0, 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 on device Samsung.

I am using `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Which version of Lifecycle you are using ? add the dependency with question .

Comment: I am using `1.1.1` for arch lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some bug on Samsung devices for which reflection fails, very occasionally though.

I posted this on google issue tracker and got the below answer:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124584380

Solution is to migrate to `Java 1.8 / Kotlin` and use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` that internally does not use reflection.

Haven't tried this solution yet. Will post if it worked or not.